# Get access to other classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a wpf application. There are some methods in other classes in which I want to trigger to do some work instead of trying to figure out how to rewrite them in. How is it that I can get to those classes? Would I have to for example instantiate the class? If so, once I instantiate it, how would I be able access them. Keep in mind that these classes have abstract classes on top of abstract classes.

Comment: Which other classes?  This description is certainly vague.  Maybe you want to know how code-behind works?

Comment: You definitely need to give more information here.  It's really not clear to others what you're after.

Comment: "Help me help you".  This question has nothing to do with WPF and everything to do with how object oriented programming works (assuming this is in C#). I would recommend when asking questions to post code examples to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do looks dangerous to me. Try to understand what those classes are for and ask some advice from a colleague. He will definitely help you on that. You will not find an answer here because your situation is too specific and we have no sample code.
Also, some [OOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx) lecture will help you a lot.